# How to compare two bits of SQL code in Power BI?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, powerbi

I am a very new to PowerBI. I have a task where I need to highlight the SQL code by comparing prior and current version, please see below example

| Prior code | Current Code |
| --- | --- |
| select case when A=1 then 2 else 3 end as test from table | select case when A=3 then 2 else 3 end as test from tableA |

I need to show like below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNk9o.png)

Is this possible in PowerBI? If yes - can I show the difference that also helps?

Please advice or suggest

Comment: Power BI is most definitely _not_ the tool for this. Code comparison is a well established process with many mature tools. Perhaps you can start with Visual Studio code. If you are checking your SQL code into Git, there are also many tools attached to that process (including VS Code)

Answer (score 0):

Power Bi is business analytic tool, Im not sure you can do what you are asking, You can do it from vs code, git, git extension like version control software.